# Check if RGB values of an image meet conditions without a loop

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a coloured image img, as defined below.  And I have range values for R, G, and B: R1, R2, B1, and so on...

Now I want to set all RGB values of an image to [255, 0, 0] if the following conditions satisfied
    [(R1 > R & R < R2) & (G1 > G & G < G2) & (B1 > B & B < B2)].

I can do this by looping to all RGB values of the image, but I don't want to do it that way.  Is there a way that I can implement this one in the NumPyish way?  Or what is the best way to implement this one?

```
img = cv2.imread(file)
R1 = 91
R2 = 150
G1 = 10
G2 = 100
B1 = 100
B2 = 150
```

Comment: You are going to be using some kind of loop even if it is numpy doing it for you.

Comment: The optimal way of doing this is with `inRange()` https://www.learnopencv.com/color-spaces-in-opencv-cpp-python/ - especially since you are already using **OpenCV**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the colour comparison for each colour channel at once using numpy like `img[:,:,2] > R1` for the red channel. You can combine all these together like so.

```py
# opencv stores colour channels in BGR order by default normally
img[(img[:,:,0] > B1) &(img[:,:,0] < B2) & (img[:,:,1] > G1) & (img[:,:,1] < G2) & (img[:,:,2] > R1) & (img[:,:,2] < R2),:] = [0,0,255]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the elements `R1,R2,...,G1,G2,...,B1,B2,...` into an array and check for the conditions in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
R = 90 # example
array=np.array([[R1,R2],[G1,G2],[B1,B2]])
```

And using the `numpy where` function, you can specify the condition, e.g `<R` and the operations if the condition is satisfied or not satisfied.

```
np.where(array[:,0]<R, 255, array[:,0]) # for R1,G1,B1
np.where(array[:,1]<R, 0, array[:,0]) # for R2,G2,B2 and so on
```

You can modify from here.

`np.where(array[:,0]<R, 255, array[:,0])` goes through elements and if an element is less than R replaces the element with 255 and if not then does not modify the element.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function and apply it over your elements. Might still use a for loop internally. Images are BGR format in opencv.

```
func = lambda x: [0, 0, 255] if (R1 > x[2] & x[2] < R2) & (G1 > x[1] & x[1] < G2) & (B1 > x[0] & x[0] < B2) else x
img2 = numpy.apply_along_axis(func, 0, img)
```